# Jquery + asp.net not being detected in one of the pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I currently have this format in all of my pages. However in one of my pages a script file is not detecting jquery. I have something like this in the end of my main cshtml page

```
@section stylesheets {
   ....
}

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Panel.js"></script>
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //do something
});
</script>
```

Now my `Panel.js` has a function whose jquery statement keeps failing with the message
`Panel.js:601 Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function`

```
This is in Panel.js
function showResponse()
{
    var result= $('#actionSelect option:selected')();
    
}
```

Any suggestions on what might be happening here ? I have tried numerous things but I am still not sure why this is happening ? Jquery works fine on scripts of other pages. It also does not complain  on `$(document).ready`

Comment: are you sure that the jquery.js above the panel.js

Comment: @M.skr yes. I made sure its above the `Panel.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was invalid
`var result= $('#actionSelect option:selected')();`
it should have been
`var result= $('#actionSelect option:selected').text();`